# Why does this SUM() function take so long in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

This is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM bill WHERE name = 'peter'
```

There are 800K+ rows in the table. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` says:

```
Aggregate  (cost=288570.06..288570.07 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=537213.327..537213.328 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on bill  (cost=0.00..288320.94 rows=498251 width=4) (actual time=48385.201..535941.041 rows=800947 loops=1)
Filter: ((name)::text = 'peter'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 8
Total runtime: 537213.381 ms
```

All rows are affected, and this is correct. But why so long? A similar query without `WHERE` runs way faster:

```
ANALYZE EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(amount) FROM bill
Aggregate  (cost=137523.31..137523.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2198.663..2198.664 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using idx_amount on bill  (cost=0.00..137274.17 rows=498268 width=4) (actual time=0.032..1223.512 rows=800955 loops=1)
Heap Fetches: 533399
Total runtime: 2198.717 ms
```

I have an index on `amount` and an index on `name`. Have I missed any indexes?

ps. I managed to solve the problem just by adding a new idex `ON bill(name, amount)`. I didn't get why it helped, so let's leave the question open for some time...

Comment: either `WHERE user = 'peter'` is not selective enough and/or there are no usable indices on the `user` column. BTW: `user` is a reserved word; try to avoid using it as an identifier.

Comment: Not massively familiar with postgres - but for MSSQL if you have a multicolumn index (amount,name) in this case, then it is only used if the valid column is first. So if you create an index on name along this may improve your results.

Comment: @SteveHomer I have two indexes, one on `name`, and one on `amount`

Comment: what is the datatype of `name`?

Comment: Did you run each query several times?  It looks to me like in the first query, the database was cold and all data had to be read from disk.  While in subsequent queries, the data was already in memory and so is much faster.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are searching for a specific name, you should have an index that has name as the first column, e.g. `CREATE INDEX IX_bill_name ON bill( name )`.

But Postgres can still opt to do a full table scan if it estimates your index to not be specific enough, i.e. if it thinks it is faster to just scan all rows and pick the matching ones instead of consulting an index and start jumping around in the table to gather the matching rows. Postgres uses a cost-based estimation technique that weights random disk reads to be more expensive than sequential reads.

For an index to actually be used in your situation, there should be no more than 10% of the rows matching what you are searching for. Since most of your rows have name=peter it is actually faster to do a full table scan.

As to why the SUM without filtering runs faster has to do with overall width of the table. With a where-clause, postgres has to sequentially read all rows in the table so it can disregard those that do not match the filter. Without a where-clause, postgres can instead read all the amounts from the index. Because the index on amounts contains the amounts and pointers to each corresponding rows, but no other data from the table, it is simply less data to wade through. Based on the big different in performance I guess you have quite a lot of other fields in your table..

Comment: thanks for your explanation, it helped. But this is how I fixed the problem: `CREATE INDEX idx ON bill(name, amount)`

Comment: @yegor256 With this index postgres can do index only scan with filtering so it is close to the case without filtering. You traded query speed for disc space and speed of all dml operations on this table so it is not the fix but a trade off.